# Morphing between two cartograms made in QGIS

Tags: qgis, animation, cartogram

I've used the Cartogram plugin for QGIS to produce several cartograms.

Is there a way to animate the transitions between shapefiles / svgs using QGIS?

Comment: The Time Manager plugin is the only tool I know of to create animations in QGIS. It would require you to have several intermediate stages of data (basically the stillshots of the animation). I don't know of any easy way to create those intermediate layers. If you rule out doing it in QGIS, this question would have no GIS component so it would be better off on a different SE site, such as [video.se] or [graphicdesign.se].